# VBA excel why the word "EnableEvents" is not capitalized in my VBA coding?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

The "e" is not capitalized:
My code:  Application.enableEvents
Should be:  Application.EnableEvents

... right?  Why my "e" is not capitalized automatically?  My codes:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

```
 Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
 Application.OnKey "{ESC}", ""
 On Error Resume Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False:  Application.enableEvents = False:  Application.Cursor = xlWait

 Sheets("Splash").Activate
 Range("C65").Select:   SendKeys ("~"):  MsgBox ("OK"):  Sleep 200
 Call Keys_Disable
 Application.OnKey Key:="+{INSERT}", Procedure:="Key_PV"     '<<< PasteValue only...
 Application.OnKey Key:="^v", Procedure:="Key_PV"            '<<< PasteValue only...
 Application.OnKey Key:="+{DEL}", Procedure:="Key_Undo"      '<<< Allow undo...
 Application.OnKey Key:="^z", Procedure:="Key_Undo"          '<<< Allow undo...
```

etc.
etc.

Comment: Please show the full line of code.

Comment: I put in the first part of the codes... Also, this "e" is not capitalized everywhere for "Application.enableEvents".... very weird...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA is case-insensitive, so any given identifier name is only stored internally with whatever last casing it was declared with - you probably have declared a `enableEvents` variable somewhere.

You can "fix" the casing by declaring a variable by that name:

```
Dim EnableEvents
```

Then hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or otherwise moving out of that line to get the VBE to process it - and then you can delete that bogus variable; anything named `enableEvents`, `enableevents`, or `ENABLEEVENTS` will now show up as `EnableEvents`.

Comment: Wow Mathieu!!  That fixed it!!... Yes, I disabled EnableEvents with a simple Sub:  Application.EnableEvents = False... I think that caused it, but Dim EnableEvents like you said, fixed it....thank you!